# Controlling sprite animation with keypress

Tags: image, animation, pygame, sprite-sheet

I've been working on a boxing game.  After spending hours creating a sprite sheet, I now have trouble using it in my game.  The animations load fine, but I can't seem to find a good way to control them.  I would like to have each line of my sprite_sheet loop only once, but using this code, the punch keeps looping until I release the key.

```
left_jab = False

for event in pygame.event.get():

   if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
       quit()

   elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

       if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
           left_jab = True

   elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:

       if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
           left_jab = False

   if left_jab:
        player.update(dt)
        player.render_left_jab(gameDisplay)
```

This is part of the player class:

```
    def update(self, dt):

    self.current_time += dt

    if self.current_time >= self.animation_time:
        self.current_time = 0

        if self.current_image >= self.numImages - 1:
            self.current_image = 0

        else:
            self.current_image += 1
```

Is there an easier way to do this?
There are 8 images per line in my sprite sheet.  Is it just a matter of creating a smoother animation using more images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about how long the animation (or the punching) should take, and if that time is up, set `left_jab` to `False` again.

A very simple way is to change your code to something like:

```
if self.current_image >= self.numImages - 1:
    self.current_image = 0
    left_jab = False
```

So once the animation looped once, we just stop it.

Of course this is not the final solution, but you'll get the idea. You didn't show your full code but I suggest moving all logic that belongs to the player/boxer entity into its class (the check for key presses, the `left_jab` flag etc.).

Comment: Thanks, that worked!
I currently have most of the code in main.py.  Then I have one class for player and one class for opponent.  Are you suggesting I create a class for the fight itself?

Comment: I also seem to have an issue with the image loop sometimes just picking up halfway through the animation when i press a key.  It looks very choppy.